# Angular post request not working not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my module:

```
angular.module('ngDetails', ['])
.constant('API', 'http://myserver.com/dir/api')
.controller('carDetails', carDetails)
```

Here is my controller:

```
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService) {
  CarDetailService.getCar().success(function(details) {

    $scope.details = details;

    carID = $scope.details['ID'];

    $scope.approve = function($scope, $http, API, Message) {
      $http.post( API + '/car/' + carID , { Message: Message } ).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.approve = data;
      })
    }

  });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="carDetails">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" ng-model="Message"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="approve()">Approve</button>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is send a post request to my API that sends with it a message that a user puts in inside of a textarea box before they hit the "approve" button. But when I hit the "approve" button I get an error saying - "  Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at m.$scope.approve  ". How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you need to require the DI items on your constructor , and not in the approve function.

```
  function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService, $http, API, Message) {
  CarDetailService.getCar().success(function(details) {

    $scope.details = details;

    carID = $scope.details['ID'];

    $scope.approve = function() {
      $http.post( API + '/car/' + carID , { Message: Message } ).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.approve = data;
      })
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with the angular services or your own build services and you want to use them in controller on services you need to inject them

```
 $scope.approve = function($scope, $http, API, Message) {
      $http.post( API + '/car/' + carID , { Message: Message } ).//$http?
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.approve = data;
      })
```

Inject like this

```
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService,$http) {
  CarDetailService.getCar().success(function(details) {

    $scope.details = details;

    carID = $scope.details['ID'];

    $scope.approve = function($scope, $http, API, Message) {
      $http.post( API + '/car/' + carID , { Message: Message } ).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.approve = data;
      })
    }

  });
```